# FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS with windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds set to true causing my navigation bar turns black in Android Emulator (

Tags: android, statusbar, android-navigation-bar

My Requirement is to make status bar fully transparent without any overlay and navigation bar white.For that I used FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS and fitsSystemWindows=true but there was an overlay on status bar on some devices, So I applied FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag which made my status bar and navigation bar transparent.

Since, I didn't want my navigation bar to be transparent so I used windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds=true.Now the navigation bar became black on Android Emulator (Pixel 3XL, API28, PIE 9.0). Its colour is not changing now for this particular emulator.Though it is showing white navigation which is my requirement in Redmi and Realme phones. But in Android Emulator (Pixel 3XL, API28, PIE 9.0) the Navigation bar is still black.

I took the reference of this library https://github.com/laobie/StatusBarUtil also to meet my requirements but this library project is behaving same as my current situation(i.e working on real devices but in emulator mentioned above it is showing black navigation bar)

[image]